# A question on genus fields and p-primary class groups

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $k$ be an imaginary quadratic field and $p$ a prime such that $p = \mathfrak{p}\overline{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $k$.  Let $k_n$ be an extension of $k$ such that $Gal(k_n/k) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and suppose that $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\overline{\mathfrak{p}}$ are totally ramified.  Let $L_n$ be the genus field for $k_n/k$ (i.e. the maximal unramified extension of $k_n$ such that $L_n$ is Abelian over $k$). Let $A_n$ be the $p$-primary part of the class group of $k_n$ and $Gal(k_n/k) = \langle \sigma \rangle$. Also, assume that the $p$-primary class group for $k$ is trivial.

**Here is my question:** Why is it that $[L_n:k_n] = [A_n:A_n^{\sigma -1}]$?  The paper I am reading says that this is well known, but doesn't give any references.

I know that $L_n$ is contained in the class field $\bar{L}_n$ of $k_n$ since $L_n$ is unramified Abelian over $k_n$, but I'm having trouble seeing how $L_n$ being Abeian over $k$ implies $[L_n:k_n] = [A_n:A_n^{\sigma -1}]$.  The total ramification of $\mathfrak{p}, \overline{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $k_n/k$ must also play a role.  Any hints or references are appreciated!

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: @KentaS https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X74900341

Comment: Won't we have $(\sigma(I),F_n/k_n)=\sigma(I,F_n/k_n)\sigma^{-1}$ with $F_n$ the maximal abelian unramified extension of $k_n$ and $\sigma$ extended to an automorphism of $F_n/k$. So the Artin map should give an isomorphism between the commutator subgroup of $Gal(F_n/k)$ and $\langle \{ I \sigma(I)^{-1},I \in Cl(k_n)\}\rangle$

Comment: @reuns Ah, so this implies $Gal(L_n/ k_n) \cong Cl(k_n)/ Cl(k_n)^{\sigma -1}$. 
 $Gal(k_n/k)$ acts trivially on $Cl(k_n)/Cl(k_n)^{\sigma -1}$, and so the norm from $k_n$ to $k$ acts as the $p^n$-th power map.  But I'm not sure if the norm kills everything in $Cl(k_n)/Cl(k_n)^{\sigma -1}$.  Does this mean the statement in my question is off?